# Server with two 32-bit Oracle Clients installed. How do I know which Oracle Client I am using?

Tags: oracle, ssis

We have an SSIS package that we are runnuing with the 32 bit DTEXEC.exe utility that connects to an Oracle database. It is running on a server that has two versions of the Oracle Client installed: 11.2g and 12c.

How do I know which version of the Oracle Client is being used?

The configuration file (dtsconfig) conenction info is shown below:

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[SsisConnectionObjectName].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ServerName.sys.CompanyName.com)(PORT=9999)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SidName)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=MyUserId;Password=MyPassword;</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Well, do you have ORACLE_HOME set and also in your path?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. when I open up a command window and ECHO %ORACLE_HOME% it just displays back the variable name, which I believe means it isn't set. As for the Path variable, I do not have access to the server but are you saying that it would use the first oracle client path in the Path variable? If so, is it even possible to control which client software, in my case an SSIS package, an app uses? The serevr admin was sugegsting that we leave the old 11.3g client installed as well as 12c in case some programs need to use it. My question is, if you have both, how can a package choose?

Comment: a "quick and dirty" way to determine which one is in use is to delete the TNSNAMES file from one of the client folders, if your SSIS fails it's using that one, if it doesn't it's using the other